# Python using Fuzzywuzzy to compare a csv to excel and copy data from csv file to excel based approximate data in the excel file

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have the following code that will copy and paste data from a csv file to an excel file (it compares names of employees and copies the date). The only problem is that it only copies dates for exact matches (William to William, as opposed to Will to William). Is there anyway to use fuzzywuzzy to make it also copy data from approximate matches. The code is listed below.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import csv
import openpyxl
import datetime


training_updates = {};
with open('from.csv') as frombook:
    reader = csv.DictReader(frombook)
    for row in reader:
        if int(row["ViewTotalScore"]) > 70:
            training_updates[(row["ViewerInfo"].strip("[]").lower())] = (row["DateTime"])[:-8].rstrip()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('to.xlsm', data_only=True, keep_vba=True)
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('to.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
sheetcheck = wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb.get_sheet_names()[0])
sheetwrite = wb2.get_sheet_by_name(wb2.get_sheet_names()[0])
for rowNum in range(2, sheetcheck.max_row):
    if sheetcheck.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value is not None:
        employee = str(sheetcheck.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value).lower()
        if employee in training_updates:
            xldate = datetime.datetime.strptime(training_updates[employee], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            sheetwrite.cell(row=rowNum, column=5).value = xldate
            print("Updated record for " + employee)

wb2.save('updatedto.xlsm')
```

I have used fuzzywuzzy extractOne to try to pull them as well and that hasn't yielded any results for fuzzy matches:

```
import csv
import openpyxl
import datetime
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

training_updates = {};

# create workbook object 'wb' from 'from.xlsm'
with open('from.csv') as frombook:
    reader = csv.DictReader(frombook)
    for row in reader:
        if int(row["ViewTotalScore"]) > 70:
            training_updates[(row["ViewerInfo"].strip("[]").lower())] = (row["DateTime"])[:-8].rstrip()


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('to.xlsm', data_only=True, keep_vba=True)
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('to.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
sheetcheck = wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb.get_sheet_names()[0])
sheetwrite = wb2.get_sheet_by_name(wb2.get_sheet_names()[0])
for rowNum in range(2, sheetcheck.max_row):
      if sheetcheck.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value is not None:
        employee = str(sheetcheck.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value).lower()
        employeemispelled = process.extractOne([training_updates],choices=employee,score_cutoff=15)
        if employeemispelled in training_updates:
            xldate = datetime.datetime.strptime(training_updates[employee],"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            sheetwrite.cell(row=rowNum, column=5).value = xldate
            print ("Updated record for " + employee)
wb2.save('updatedto.xlsm')
```

Comment: I was able to get close to what I needed with the following code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get close to what I was trying to do with:

```
import re
import csv
import openpyxl
import datetime

# define our dictionaries
training_updates = {}
update_exceptions = {}

training_name =  ""
regex = " \([A-Z0-9]*\)"

# create our counter variables
counttotal = 0
countupdated = 0
exception_count = 1

# open the csv we want to pull our info from
with open('from.csv') as frombook:
    reader = csv.DictReader(frombook)
    for row in reader:
        training_name = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', row["ï»¿Sort Title"])
        print(training_name)
        break

    # loop through the rows and check if the user's total score is greater than 70
    for row in reader:
        if int(row["ViewTotalScore"]) > 70:
            # if it is, add 1 to our total count and add the record to the update dictionary
            training_updates[(row["ViewerInfo"].strip("[]").lower())] = (row["DateTime"])[:-8].rstrip()

counttotal = len(training_updates)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('to.xlsm', data_only=True, keep_vba=True)
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('to.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
wbexception = openpyxl.load_workbook('template.xlsx')

sheetcheck = wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb.get_sheet_names()[0])
sheetwrite = wb2.get_sheet_by_name(wb2.get_sheet_names()[0])
sheetexception = wbexception.get_sheet_by_name(wbexception.get_sheet_names()[0])

for rowNum in range(1, sheetcheck.max_row):
    if sheetcheck.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value is not None:     
        employee = str(sheetcheck.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value).lower()        
        empname = employee.split(" ")
        if len(empname) >= 2:
            empsearchname = empname[0] + " " + empname[1]
            if empsearchname in training_updates:
                xldate = datetime.datetime.strptime(training_updates[empsearchname], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                sheetwrite.cell(row=rowNum, column=14).value = xldate
                print("Updated record for " + employee)
                countupdated+=1
                del training_updates[empsearchname]

print(str(countupdated)+" of "+str(counttotal)+" updated.")
print(str(len(training_updates))+" records still need to be updated.")

wb2.save('updatedto.xlsm')

for key, value in training_updates.items():
    exception_count+=1
    xldate = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    sheetexception.cell(row=exception_count, column = 1).value = key
    sheetexception.cell(row=exception_count, column = 2).value = value
    print("Noting exception for "+key)

exception_count-=1
print("Report generated for "+str(exception_count)+" exceptions. "+str(exception_count)+" + "+str(countupdated)+" = "+str(counttotal))
wbexception.save('update_exceptions.xlsx')
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize there was an "accept" option. I have checked it accepted.